# How to create with association using Sequelize when using id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a `warmup` and a `warmup_step`. I am trying to create a `warmup` [with an association](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html#creating-with-associations)
however when I try and create, it does not map the `warmup_id` to the `warmup_step`. What am I doing wrong?

```js
// Warmup

module.exports = (sequelize, DATATYPES) => {
  const Warmup = sequelize.define(
    "warmup",
    {
      duration: { type: DATATYPES.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
      name: { type: DATATYPES.STRING, allowNull: false },
    },
    { underscored: true }
  );

  // Assign an associate function on the model
  Warmup.associate = function (models) {
    models.Warmup.hasMany(models.WarmupStep);
  };

  return Warmup;
};
```

```js
// Warmup Step

module.exports = (sequelize, DATATYPES) => {
  const WarmupStep = sequelize.define(
    "warmup_step",
    {
      duration: { type: DATATYPES.INTEGER, allowNull: false }, // seconds
      exercise_id: { type: DATATYPES.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
      warmup_id: { type: DATATYPES.INTEGER, allowNull: false }, // Map to parent Warmup.
      step_index: { type: DATATYPES.INTEGER, allowNull: false }, // position in warmup.
    },
    { underscored: true }
  );

  // Assign an associate function on the model
  WarmupStep.associate = function (models) {
    models.WarmupStep.belongsTo(models.Warmup, { foreignKey: "warmup_id" });
  };

  return WarmupStep;
};
```

Create function:

```js
  Warmup.create(
    {
      name,
      duration,
      warmup_steps,
    },
    {
      include: [WarmupStep],
    }
  )
    .then((data) => res.send(data))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("here");
      console.log(err);
    });
```

I would expect the `warmup` to be created and then use the id for the `warmup_steps` but it is giving me the error `message: 'warmup_step.warmup_id cannot be null'`. I assumed this is what creating with an association did for you? Or do I have to do this in two calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indicate **warmup_id** in the hasMany association as well:

```
models.Warmup.hasMany(models.WarmupStep, { foreignKey: "warmup_id" });
```